# NextAuth Credentials, adding more to the user scheme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-auth

Nextauth with mysql persisting users.

I'm trying out this NextAuth thing to see if this is something I like. So far so good. There is one thing tho which is buggin me and that would be the user scheme. By default it returns a name, image and the last one I forgot.

I'd like to add more to this scheme and found some ways to do it by looking at google, however those I tried did not work.

One example I found is by extending the model which clearly makes sense...
The issue here is then me, I do not know what to change in the code below to make it work with my NextAuth credentials provider. As shown below, this doesnt work.

**projectfolder -> models -> index.js**

```
import User, { UserSchema } from "./User"
export default {
  User: {
    model: User,
    schema: UserSchema
  }
}
```

**projectfolder -> models -> user.js**

```
import Adapters from "next-auth/adapters"

// Extend the built-in models using class inheritance
export default class User extends Adapters.TypeORM.Models.User.model {
  constructor(name, email, image, emailVerified, roles) {
    super(name, email, image, emailVerified)
    if (roles) { this.roles = roles}
  }
}

export const UserSchema = {
  name: "User",
  target: User,
  columns: {
    ...Adapters.TypeORM.Models.User.schema.columns,
    roles: {
      type: "varchar",
      nullable: true
    },
  },
}
```

In my [...nextauth].js file I have my provider, in this provider i've added an profile() field with the extra fields. This did not solve the issue.

```
profile(profile) {
    return {
        name: profile.name,
        email: profile.email,
        role: profile.role
    };
  },
```

Please correct me if I am wrong but if I am using credentials, then I need to replace the "TypeORM" with something else, correct? How about the path for the files, are they correct?

This should clearly be quite easy but am I missing something or am I doing something wrong? I feel like there is a lack of documentation on extending the user model for mysql.

I've doubled checked that the role is being retrieved from the database and then added to the user variable shown here:

async authorize ....

```
const user = {
   name: result.display_name,
   role: result.role_name,
   email: result.email
}
```

Although I can see the role being set in the variable with my console.log(), I still cannot access the role and that I suspect is because of the model. How would I resolve this? Thanks a lot in advance.

Any ideas?

----------------------- UPDATES ------------------------

Btw, here is my callback

```
callbacks: {  
    async signIn({ user, account, profile, email }) {
      console.log("user", user);
      return true;
    },

  },
```

and this is what it returns (shortened)

```
token: {
        token: { name: 'Firstname Lastname', email: 'test@mail.com' },
        user: {
          name: 'Firstname Lastname',
          role: 'administrator',
          email: 'test@mail.com'
        },
        account: { type: 'credentials', provider: 'credentials' },
        isNewUser: false,
        iat: 1634193197,
        exp: 1636785197
      }
```

Comment: Found this: "Built in providers don't take additional functions like profile , they are for custom providers. : ) next-auth.js.org/providers/google" If this is true then it means I have to set the roles in a different way than by using profile()

Comment: Is there no one who can assist? :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to TypeORM and I am facing the same problems as people here.

What I've done was create a separate Entity which I called `users_info` to store the other information and retrieve it after signing in.

It looks like this:

```
import { UserEntity } from './NextAuthEntities';

@Entity({ name: 'users_info' })
export class MemberEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('increment')
  id!: number;

  @OneToOne(() => UserEntity)
  @JoinColumn({
    name: 'auth_id',
    referencedColumnName: 'id',
  })
  auth_id!: UserEntity;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', nullable: true })
  full_name!: string | null;
  
  // etc

}
```

Then, I created a handshake API route to retrieve users_info if the user is signed-in.

When I added a new @Column on my custom UsersEntity, it threw me an error when I tried to login. It seems like `TypeORMLegacyAdapter` can't be extended or be different from the default UserEntity.

Hope it helps